# "Косит под кого-то" — ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

С одной стороны, "чей-то глаз кос**и**т" и выражение от этого значения как раз, а с другой, не слышал, чтобы делали такое же ударение в этом выражении. Хотя Грамота [поддерживает](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) ударение "кос**и**т" (2-е значение). Права ли она?

Comment: Народ, я удалю вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Да люди только и говорят "ко́сит под кого-то".

У Грамоты вначале совсем другое:
[image]

Здесь в словаре Кузнецова во втором пункте указано другое ударение (ко́сишь):
http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Kosit-61734.html

В любом случае не люди подстраиваются под словари, а словари под людей.

Comment: Точно, не заметил начала! Только "косИт глазом" по-другому всё равно не скажешь — меня ещё папа учил так ударение ставить!

Comment: При разных значениях ударение может отличатся, даже если прототип другой.

Comment: Какой такой прототип?

Comment: В прямом смысле - слово, от которого пошло другое выражение/слово/значение. Чуть не так выразился: даже если прототип тот же.

Comment: А-а, тогда понимаю.